# Move and automatically rename(customized) a file

Tags: php, fuelphp

I need to move a file from a path ($old_path) to another path ($new_path).

Before move the file to the $new_path I have to check if I already have a file with the same 'filename.ext' inside.

If I don't, 
  I just move the file from the $old_path to the $new_path, 
else
  I have a file with the same name and I want to first rename the new file with an 1_ before, so the new file will be '1_filename.ext'

Then I receive another file and I check again for the existence of the 'filename.ext' in the $new_path.

Again I have to rename the file, but this time I can't rename it to '1_filename.ext', because there is already a file with this name.

Keeping in mind what I want to do, how can I create the new file name automatically, generating, each time, the last filename.ext + 1 for the prefix ?

If the $new-path is empty, first file will be filename.ext

Second time, i will rename (automatically) the new file to 1_filename.ext

Third time, i will rename (automatically) the new file to 2_filename.ext

and so on ...

Looking for you advices.

P.S. If you have something for FuelPHP it will be great, else ... plain PHP will be just fine !

That's waht I did until now :

```
$fresh_files = File::read_dir(DOCROOT . DS . 'opta_archive');

foreach ($fresh_files as $fresh_file) 
{

$file_name = basename($fresh_file, '.xml');

if (file_exists(DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$file_name))
{
    //create a new unique name for the new file
    //and then move it in our archive folder

}
else
{
    //move the file in our archive folder
    File::rename(DOCROOT.DS.'opta_archive'.DS.$fresh_file, DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$fresh_file);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you want to add your code to the question?

Comment: first of all I don't understand the '-' vote. The code for what ? I'm asking for a code sugestion !

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. If you got a specific question or problem with your code, we're happy to help. Your question reads very like "Please can someone write this for me"

Comment: Thank you for adding your code. I've added an answer.

Comment: This is not a class room where you learn programming. Before asking a question you need to do two things: 1. read the manual and if you can't find what you are looking for there 2. ask yourself if what you want to ask is an actual real problem or just your inability to solve it. Sorry if I seemed a bit harsh but you have to do struggle and search for a solution before asking someone here to spend time on a very basic problem like this one.

Comment: Whau, seems that you are preety good. Why don't you offer a solution, to my problem ? I didn't put the code, because I didn't think that is someoane interested to see an if ... else statement, I was interested just for the part of the script which automatically create the number before the filename. But anyway, there are things to do ... not to speak without offering a solution or an indication ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want.

It checks to see if the file exists in your `fantomic_archive` folder; if it doesn't, it just moves the file over.

Otherwise, it goes through a loop - it adds a number to the start of the filename, and checks to see if that number exists. As soon as it generates a unique filename, it renames the file to that.

```
$fresh_files = File::read_dir(DOCROOT . DS . 'opta_archive');

foreach ($fresh_files as $fresh_file) {
    $file_name = basename($fresh_file, '.xml');

    if (! file_exists(DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$file_name)) {
        //create a new unique name for the new file
        //and then move it in our archive folder

    File::rename(DOCROOT.DS.'opta_archive'.DS.$fresh_file, DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$fresh_file);
    } else {
        $count = 1;
        while (file_exists(DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$count . "_" . $file_name)) {
            $count++;
        }
        File::rename(DOCROOT.DS.'opta_archive'.DS.$fresh_file, DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$count . "_" . $fresh_file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't exactly does do job. Whw ? Because, first time the name of the file from opta archive is file.ext. Your script moves the file in the fantomic_archive, and rename it (for the first time) to 1_file.ext. Then I receive a new file in opta_archive, named as the first one, file.ext, and this time, the script doesn't do the job.

Comment: You should be able to figure out how to debug it, though

Comment: Yeap, from here it's just fine, thks.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution which works, based on the ideea provided by 'andrewsi' is :

```
$fresh_files = File::read_dir(DOCROOT . DS . 'opta_archive');
```

foreach ($fresh_files as $fresh_file) 
{
    $file_name = basename($fresh_file);

`$count = 1;

if (file_exists(DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$count . "_" . $file_name))
{
    $count++;

    File::rename(DOCROOT.DS.'opta_archive'.DS.$fresh_file, DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$count . "_" . $file_name);
}
else
{
    File::rename(DOCROOT.DS.'opta_archive'.DS.$fresh_file, DOCROOT.DS.'fantomic_archive'.DS.$count . "_" . $file_name);
}`

}